# Can I move Walking Dead Season 1 datas from Windows to Mac OS

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I have Windows version of *The Walking Dead Game Season 1* and played it on my Mac with wine. Now I have save files and I want to buy **Season 2** Mac version from Steam.

Season 2 needs Season 1's save datas to fetch decisions from there. Can I use Season 1 (Windows)'s save files with Season 2 (Mac, downloaded from steam) ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not. Saves on on different platforms use different file formats and cannot be transferred between platforms.

You'll need to use the random choices generated when you start a game, buy and play the mac version of season one, or find a save from the mac version from someone else.

Source: https://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/53755/cross-platform-saves

Comment: oh, no. It was important for me. When buy from Steam can I both of Windows and Mac versions? Or only one of them? I didn't download something from Steam before.

Comment: just found a [reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheWalkingDeadGame/comments/1tzfzl/season_1_save_thread_a_place_to_download_saves/) for sharing Season 1 save files.  They aren't mentioning these files for Mac or Windows. So maybe save files are same for both. Just removed *Accepted Answer* to see if new answers will come.